# How to conditionally invoke spring validators

Tags: java, spring, validation

I have a model like below. Existing code already has validations on individual properties. Now I have a requirement to ignore existing validations on billing_country and address if `buyer.method` is `foo`. I was thinking I could have a custom validator at `buyer` level, check for method and invoke validations only when `buyer.method!=foo`. Is this a valid approach? Are there any better alternatives?

```
"buyer": {
    "method": "foo",
    "instruments": [
      {
        "card": {
          "type": "MASTERCARD",
          "number": "234234234234234",
          "expire_month": "12",
          "expire_year": "2017",
          "billing_country" : "US"
          "Address" : {
             "line1": "summer st",
             "city": "Boston"
             "country": "US"
           }
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's two ways to do this.

You can either

1. create a custom validation annotation and validator which checks the value of `method` and then applies to appropriate validations to the other fields
2. use [validation groups](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkagv.html), where you manually check the value of `method`, then choose which group to use; your annotated fields will then need to be changed to only be applied when that group is active.

**Option #1**

Define a class-level annotation:

```
@Target({ TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = { MethodAndInstrumentsValidator.class })
@Documented
public @interface ValidMethodAndInstruments {
    String message() default "{my.package.MethodAndInstruments.message}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Define a validator:

```
public class MethodAndInstrumentsValidator 
             implements ConstraintValidator<ValidMethodAndInstruments, Buyer> {
    public final void initialize(final ValidMethodAndInstruments annotation) {
        // setup
    }

    public final boolean isValid(final Buyer value, 
                                 final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        // validation logic
        if(!"foo".equals(value.getMethod())) {
            // do whatever conditional validation you want
        }
    }

}
```

Annotate the buyer class:

```
@ValidMethodAndInstruments
public class Buyer { }
```

**Option #2**

Here, you'll have to invoke the validation manually.

First, define the validation groups:

```
public interface FooValidation {}
public interface NotFooValidation {}
```

Configure a validator:

```
@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validatorFactory() {
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}
```

In your controller(?), check the value of `method` and do the validation:

```
@Autowired
private Validator validator;

// ...

public void validate(Object a, Class<?>... groups) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> violations = validator.validate(a, groups);
    if(!violations.isEmpty()) {
        throw new ConstraintViolationException(violations);
    }
}

// ...

validate(buyer, "foo".equals(buyer.getMethod()) 
                    ? FooValidation.class 
                    : NotFooValidation.class);
```

Finally, modify the groups in your model/dto class:

```
public class Buyer {
    // ...

    @Null(groups = FooValidation.class)
    @NotNull(groups = NotFooValidation.class)
    protected String billingCountry;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@beerbajay answer helped to an extent, so I'm going to accept his answer. However I also wanted to jot down a couple of problems we ran into approach he suggested. We couldn't use `@Null` and `@NotNull` annotation on address since it could be null. Secondly since we had to wrap this in a custom Constraint validator, therefore for `NotFooValidation.class` we were getting extra validation message string that was not desired. Lastly we were not able to use groups in `@Valid` which was already present on `Address`. We tried `@Validated` but that didn't work for some reason. We ended up implementing `ReaderInterceptor` to intercept request and manually call validations that were needed. Hope this helps someone down the road.