# Custom constraintvalidator in spring boot app does not invoked

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bean-validation

I am trying to create custom validator for some class
I defined constraint as following ( according to different samples , for example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30876820/how-to-conditionally-invoke-spring-validators) )

```
@Target({ TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = { MyClassValidator.class })
@Documented
public @interface MyClassValid {
    String message() default "The password2 does not comply with the rules";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Then I created corresponding validator :

```
 public class MyClassValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyClassValid, ChangePasswordBody> {
        @Override
        public boolean isValid(ChangePasswordBody value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
            
/*This check only for sample . Ot can be replaced by other logic*/
if (value.getNewPassword().length() > 2 ) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Class to be validated :

```
@MyClassValid
public class ChangePasswordBody {
    private String oldPassword;
    private String newPassword;

    public String getOldPassword() {
        return oldPassword;
    }

    public void setOldPassword(String oldPassword) {
        this.oldPassword = oldPassword;
    }

    public String getNewPassword() {
        return newPassword;
    }
    
    public void setNewPassword(String newPassword) {
        this.newPassword = newPassword;
    }
}
```

This is code using ChangePasswordBody

```
private static void testChangePwd(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    //...
    ChangePasswordBody pwdBody = new ChangePasswordBody();
    isValidPassword(pwdBody);
    //...
}
private static void isValidPassword(ChangePasswordBody pwdBody) {
    pwdBody.setNewPassword("l"); 
}
```

I see that when executing `testChangePwd` method - MyClassValidator.isValid is not invoked. Is there something missing / wrong in the code ? Thanks in advance

Comment: why you are not using `@Size(min = 2)` of field level  instead of `ConstraintValidator` ? because in my opinion you should create something custom when spring not provide it for us.

Comment: Check for length >  2 - only sample . IsValid planned to contain more logic ( for example validation of multiple fields) . Thus I am trying to use custom validator

Comment: In this case yes I am agree, just follow @KenChan answer it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation will not take place automatically , you have to somehow invoke it using the bean validation API (e.g. `Validator`)

Presume spring-boot already auto-configures a `Validator` , in your case you could trigger the validation programatically by :

```java
private static void testChangePwd(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    
    ChangePasswordBody pwdBody = new ChangePasswordBody();
    pwdBody.setNewPassword("l");  

    Validator validator = applicationContext.getBean(Validator.class);
    Set<ConstraintViolation<ChangePasswordBody>> validationErrors =  validator.validate(pwdBody);

    //handle the validationErrors here...
}
```

But it is a very bad idea that it requires to get a bean from the spring context in the business codes as it would couple it to spring . A much better approach is to make the object that you want to validate as the method argument and validate it through executing that method.

Something likes :

```java
@Validated
public class PasswordService {

    public void changePassword(@Valid ChangePasswordBody request) {

    }
}
```

And if `ChangePasswordBody` fails the validation , it will throw `ConstraintViolationException`.

Comment: welcome. please consider to upvote or accept my answer if you find it useful to you. I spend many time to help you for free.thanks

Comment: Thanks  Ken Chan again - it looks good